# Django ModelSerializer: How do I serialize a OneToMany relation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'll try to simplify my question:

I have a model `X`. I also have a model `Y` that has a `ForeignKey` field pointing at `X`. This means in reality I could have many instances of `Y` belonging to `X` (hence one to many relation).

When I am serializing `X` though, it has no knowledge of `Y` instances pointing at it. How can I serialize all the `Y` instances that are associated with the `X` I'm currently serializing?

Do I have to have some kind of custom serialization? Or does Django support this somehow?

Comment: Why do you say the model has no knowledge of the things that are pointing to it? It does, of course. In any case, the rest-framework docs cover this explicitly​: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations

Comment: How can it? If model Y has a foreignKey pointing at X. How does X know about it? How do I serialize all the Y objects pointing at it without writing custom code? maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? I don't understand why you think this. The data is in the database, why wouldn't the model have access to it? And anyway, I **just pointed you** to the exact thing you need to do in your serializer.

Comment: Reverse relations. Ok. I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: You should also read about those in the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: Thanks. I now got it to work. If you post your initial comment as an answer I will credit you for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations) give some basic options here, but do not include what I believe to be the cleanest option; you don't normally want to change the Django Model class default `related_name` (since that breaks the convention that developers assume when working with Django), and you don't normally want to expose the `related_name` (since it's not an intuitive API field name).

You can get the best of both worlds by doing this:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.RelatedField(source='track_set',
                                      many=True,
                                      read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('tracks', ...)
```